# Problema al ejecutar funcion delete firebas en Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, typescript, google-api, google-cloud-firestore

he estado explorando un poco sobre el tema de las funciones y con ayuda de la documentación de las cloud funtions pude hacer la función delete() la probé en postman y funciona correctamente.

pero al implementarla en mi frontend en angular la función se dispara correctamente, pero el producto no lo elimina, es como si no estuviera obteniendo el id a eliminar de mi documento en el html o eso quiero pensar, intente de varias formas no consigo eliminar el documento de la colección.

cabe destacar que tengo las importaciones requeridas así como bien escritas la referencias a mi colección en la base de datos

les anexo un poco de mi código
espero puedan ilustrarme de lo que estoy haciendo mal.

**Código de mi servicio en angular:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código de mi componente donde mando a llamar mi servicio que mostré arriba:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código de la funcion delete en mi api rest con firebase:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Error que muestra el navegador al hacer click en mi botón borrar en el html
como se puede ver, muestra el error 404 que tengo definido en caso de que no se encuentre el id:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código en mi html del botón donde llamo el método para borrar:**

Nota: ya intente incluso haciendo referencia al id como parámetro asi: (click)="deleteProduct(product.id)"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @irvin Bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Intenta ajustar tu [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) a formato código, es preferible al uso de imágenes en este caso. Te invito a que revises las recomendaciones en [¿como elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Lo siento soy nuevo :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola @irvin por lo que veo en las imágenes, parece ser que tu problema puede ser debido a que cuando haces la llamada al servidor le pasas la id del producto como undefined, en la imagen que muestra los mensajes de la consola se puede ver en la llamada de "DELETE" como la id del producto es undefined.
No se si es por que no esta desplegado pero en la imagen parece que tu objeto producto no consta del campo "id" por lo que puede deberse a eso el problema.